# Mootools' .periodical equivalent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I translate some Mootools script to jQuery, and I have function:

```
play:function( delay, direction, wait )
{       
    this.isRun = this[direction].periodical(delay,this,true);
}
```

Header of one from functions which are substituted by this[direction] is:

```
next:function(manual , item)
```

Only I found is: use setInterval, but how I can pass parameters to the call?
Things such as:

```
setInterval(direction + '(' + delay + ', this)')
```

Very hard for debugging and not beautiful...
Is here more beautiful way, maybe using other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need an anonymous function.  Try something like this:

```
play:function( delay, direction, wait )
{       
    this.isRun = setInterval(function(){
            this[direction].call(this, true)
        },
        delay
    );
}
```